# Dynamic prefix on nested Ecto preloads

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, ecto

We use soft deletions in Ecto by setting a `deleted_at` column to some date.

That's why our basic schema is not `"public"`, because - by default - we don't want to query the deleted records.
Our schema is just a view that includes only records where `deleted_at=NULL`.

However, for reporting purposes, we have to preload also deleted records and we do it like that:

```
  @preload [
    tickets: {
      from(ticket in Ticket, prefix: "public"),
      [
        fees: {
          from(fee in Fee, prefix: "public"),
          [
            fee: from(fee1 in Fees.Fee, prefix: "public"),
            ticket: from(ticket1 in Ticket, prefix: "public")
          ]
        },
        taxes: from(tax in Tax, prefix: "public"),
        payments: {from(payment in Payment, prefix: "public"), [:refunds]}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way to query everything from the `"public"` schema in a simpler and less verbose way?

Comment: Have you tried using the `@schema_prefix` attribute in your Ecto Schema module, e.g. `@schema_prefix :public`

Comment: I have `@schema_prefix :filtered` there. That's the point of my question.

Comment: I see. Have you tried making a second schema module that more or less duplicates the first, but specifies the desired prefix?

Comment: It makes no sense since I have about 20 modules to preload so the duplication would be extremely painful.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to write your own modification of the `from` macro (see the `defmacro` inside `Ecto.SubQuery`) where you force the prefix option. So you might have a macro like `from_public`, but I don't think that improves your code any. Your setup is somewhat particular, and your code should help communicate that fact.  It may seem verbose, but explicitly setting the prefix helps communicate exactly what's going on with each query. YMMV

Comment: This is exactly what I've done.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to query all associations from this schema, you can set prefix in `Repo.all`, `Repo.one`, `Repo.preload` or any other function that you use to run you query:

```
Repo.all(query, prefix: "public")

Repo.one(query, prefix: "public")

Repo.preload(entity, @preload, prefix: "public")
```